# ML.NET 1.4.0 Prediction Engine throws PlatformNotSupportedException due to System.Drawing in x64 UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, ml.net

I'm relatively fresh to machine learning, Xamarin, and .NET in general - first time ever using ML.NET also.

Having recently trained an object detection model in TensorFlow, I wanted to integrate it with a Xamarin application I'm developing. Found some tutorials explaining how to import a .pb file using ML.NET and run an inference using PredictionEngine (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/run-with-ml-net-c-code-a-tensorflow-model-exported-from-azure-cognitive-services-custom-vision/).

I was making fairly steady progress until hitting this error when calling the Predict method on a PredictionEngine instance:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.Drawing is not supported on this platform.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Drawing.Bitmap.Bitmap(string)
    Microsoft.ML.Data.ImageLoadingTransformer.Mapper.MakeGetterImageDataViewType.AnonymousMethod__0(ref System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImageResizingTransformer.Mapper.MakeGetter.AnonymousMethod__1(ref System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImagePixelExtractingTransformer.Mapper.GetGetterCore.AnonymousMethod__1(ref Microsoft.ML.Data.VBuffer<TValue>)
    Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TensorFlowTransformer.TensorValueGetterVec<T>.GetTensor()
    Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TensorFlowTransformer.Mapper.UpdateCacheIfNeeded(long, Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TensorFlowTransformer.ITensorValueGetter[], string[], Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TensorFlowTransformer.Mapper.OutputCache)
    Microsoft.ML.Transforms.TensorFlowTransformer.Mapper.MakeGetter.AnonymousMethod__4(ref Microsoft.ML.Data.VBuffer<T>)
    Microsoft.ML.Data.TypedCursorable<TRow>.TypedRowBase.CreateDirectVBufferSetter.AnonymousMethod__0(TRow)
    Microsoft.ML.Data.TypedCursorable<TRow>.TypedRowBase.FillValues(TRow)
    Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngineBase<TSrc, TDst>.Predict(TSrc)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

The following are some of the NuGet packages I have installed:

- Microsoft.ML 1.4.0
- Microsoft.ML.TensorFlow 1.4.0
- Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics 1.4.0
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.9
- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist 1.15.0
- Xamarin.Essentials 1.2.0
- Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.709249

I'm attempting to build for x64 UWP. Can't seem to find this error in this context anywhere else online. This question is the most similar but doesn't help me at all: [ML.NET fails to run on uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829968/ml-net-fails-to-run-on-uwp).

I'm pretty sure I understand what the error is saying - as stated on the previously linked SO question:

> This is a .NET Standard exception that happens when the a library tries to access an API which is not actually implemented on the platform.

The real question is, why am I hitting this if the platforms I'm using are compatible with ML.NET 1.4.0?

From what I can tell, ML.NET should be able to run on both UWP (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/get-started-uwp) and x64 platforms (https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning), so what am I missing?

Any ideas/advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.ML is support uwp platform. But `System.Drawing` is the .NET namespace for working with GDI+. This technology is not available for Windows Store apps or universal Windows Apps. See [.NET for Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can draw with [Win2D](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D) lib within Windows Store apps and UWP. Pleas avoid using `System.Drawing` in uwp project.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity Nico - my only concern is that the call stack provided by the exception seems to indicate that System.Drawing is actually being called somewhere by the Microsoft.ML implementation. If it was my own code throwing the error I'd be more than happy to switch System.Drawing out with Win2D or something else. Have I misunderstood that call stack?

Comment: Looks to me like it's coming out of this file: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/4ec2f9c6dc08e8079338546b31f260d0715db45c/src/Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics/ImageResizer.cs If you want to use this in UWP I suspect you'll need to get ML.NET folks to add a try/catch and workaround for you.

Comment: Right. I can see now that his has been briefly discussed before: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3154. At least this answers my question - I'm not really missing anything, it's just that ML.NET doesn't really support UWP in full...

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer for now: ML.NET does not have image support for UWP and there are currently no plans to provide it.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3154#issuecomment-573178943